# Databinding not working in AngularJS

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

I am new to AngularJS, I am learning it from an O'Reilly book. Below is a simple shopping cart code that is given as an example in the book. I tried running it, but it is not working and I cannot figure out the reason why, any help regarding this is appreciated, helps me move on with the studies.Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app ="myApp">
<head>
<title>Shoppin Cart</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller = 'CartController'>
    <h1>Your Order</h1>
    <div ng-repeat = 'item in items'>
    <span>{{ item.title }}</span>
        <input ng-model = 'item.qauntity'>
        <span>{{ item.price | currency }}</span>
        <span> {{ item.price * item.quantity | currency }}</span>
        <button ng-click = "remove($index)">Remove</button>
    </div>
    <script>
    function CartController ($scope) {
        $scope.items = [
            {title: 'Paint Pots', quantity: 25, price: 15},
            {title: 'Polka dots', quantity: 12, price: 0.25},
            {title: 'Pebbles', quantity: 18, price: 1.75}
        ];
        $scope.remove = function(index) {
            $scope.items.splice(index,1);
        }
    }

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the JSfiddle link

http://jsfiddle.net/53nkmc7o/

Comment: I have Updated your Fiddle. Check It here- http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/2820/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with **myApp** which you have used in the HTML but not in the script. Either define it in the script or remove it.

This one works fine.

```
    <!doctype html>
<html ng-app>
  <head>
    <title>My Angular App</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller = 'CartController'>
    <h1>Your Order</h1>
    <div ng-repeat = 'item in items'>
    <span>{{ item.title }}</span>
        <input ng-model = 'item.qauntity'>
        <span>{{ item.price | currency }}</span>
        <span> {{ item.price * item.quantity | currency }}</span>
        <button ng-click = "remove($index)">Remove</button>
    </div>
    <script>
    function CartController ($scope) {
        $scope.items = [
            {title: 'Paint Pots', quantity: 25, price: 15},
            {title: 'Polka dots', quantity: 12, price: 0.25},
            {title: 'Pebbles', quantity: 18, price: 1.75}
        ];
        $scope.remove = function(index) {
            $scope.items.splice(index,1);
        }
    }

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/kumareloaded/L0ff39pb/

Comment: Thanks kumar. But the code seems to be working only partially. The input field is not taking in the 'quantity' values from the controller and also, if you change the quantity in the input field the total price should dynamically change, which is not happening.

Answer (score 0):

You are specifying module `myApp` in html that doesnt exist in your script so define it and defined controller in it as your html says that `CartController` is in `MyApp` module

**Working Demo below**

```js
        angular.module('myApp',[]).controller('CartController',function ($scope) {
            $scope.items = [
                {title: 'Paint Pots', quantity: 25, price: 15},
                {title: 'Polka dots', quantity: 12, price: 0.25},
                {title: 'Pebbles', quantity: 18, price: 1.75}
            ];
            $scope.remove = function(index) {
                $scope.items.splice(index,1);
            }
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-controller = 'CartController' ng-app="myApp">
        <h1>Your Order</h1>
        <div ng-repeat = 'item in items'>
        <span>{{ item.title }}</span>
            <input ng-model = 'item.qauntity'>
            <span>{{ item.price | currency }}</span>
            <span> {{ item.price * item.quantity | currency }}</span>
            <button ng-click = "remove($index)">Remove</button>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app ="myApp">
<head>
<title>Shoppin Cart</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller = 'CartController'>
<h1>Your Order</h1>
<div ng-repeat = 'item in items'>
<span>{{ item.title }}</span>
<input ng-model = 'item.qauntity'>
<span>{{ item.price | currency }}</span>
<span> {{ item.price * item.quantity | currency }}</span>
<button ng-click = "remove($index)">Remove</button>
</div>
<script>
//create angular module name called myApp   
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
//create controller
myApp.controller('CartController', function ($scope) {

        $scope.items = [
            {title: 'Paint Pots', quantity: 25, price: 15},
            {title: 'Polka dots', quantity: 12, price: 0.25},
            {title: 'Pebbles', quantity: 18, price: 1.75}
        ];
        $scope.remove = function(index) {
            $scope.items.splice(index,1);
        }
    })

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

You will try this. you couldnt create any **myApp** angular module on your code that is the problem